# MCQ - Events in the Mitotic cycle

Tags: cell-biology, mitosis, cell-cycle

The following question confused me at first

[image]

However, I presumed that it must be in comparison to meiosis. In that case D would be correct.

However, the correct answer is A.

How can this be? I know that in mitosis it is the chromatids that are 'pulled away' to opposite poles. In meiosis, this is whole chromatids but anaphase still occurs.

I suspect I don't understand the question. Where have I gone wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cell cycle can be divided into two phases:

**1.** Interphase

**2.** M-phase(Mitotic phase)

Note: M-phase can also mean Meiotic phase but it is not the full form of the acronym.

So M-phase in mitosis has four phases:

- Prophase
- Metaphase
- **Anaphase**(your answer)
- Telophase

A mitotic cycle:

[image: ncert]

The rest of the options:

**B**. [Cytokinesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytokinesis)

> Cytoplasmic division begins during or after the late stages of nuclear division in mitosis and meiosis.

Your question doesn't seem to consider cytokinesis as a part of M-phase (i.e to be occurring during the late karyokinesis). So it has to be ruled out.(Making some assumptions as this is a key to reaching the single correct answer in MCQs, if not this would have had two **right** answers.)

**C**. DNA replication - happens in S-phase of interphase

**D**. Interphase (certainly not the one)

Source: [ncert](http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/biology/cc&cd.pdf)